# Pontryagin-reflexivity of spaces of continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces, pontrjagin-duality

It is well-known that a Banach space $V$ is always *Pontryagin-reflexive*, i.e. the natural map $V\to \text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(\text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(V, \mathbb{R}), \mathbb{R})$, where $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(-, \mathbb{R})$ is endowed with the compact-open topology, is an isomorphism (of topological vector spaces). In particular, if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, this applies to the Banach space $V=C(X)=\mathbb{R}^X$ which is also the exponential in the category of $k$-spaces (compactly generated (weak) Hausdorff spaces). So a natural question is:

What about non-compact $k$-spaces $X$? Is the space of continuous functions $C(X)$ (endowed with the exponential, i.e. compact-open topology) Pontryagin-reflexive?

Generalizing away from $k$-spaces, can we at least find some convenient category of spaces (in the technical sense) $S$ such that the natural map
$$ \mathbb{R}^X \to \text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(\text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R}^X, \mathbb{R}), \mathbb{R})              \;\;\;\;\;(X\in S)$$
is always an isomorphism? (Where $\mathbb{R}^X$ is the exponential in $S$ and the $\text{Hom}$-sets carry the subspace topology induced from the respective exponential.)

This seems like a very natural question to me. Yet, a brief literature search yielded some results concerning characterizations of Pontryagin-reflexivity of topological vector spaces, but nothing that I was able to directly apply to this question. Is there anything known about this?

EDIT: By $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(-, -)$ I mean continuous linear maps, indeed.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what you mean by $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(—,\mathbb{R})$: continuous $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps? (Because the set of *ring* homomorphisms $\mathbb{R}^X \to \mathbb{R}$ is also important and much studied.)

Comment: At any rate, I would expect the answer to have much to do with realcompactness of $X$. Did you try to work out what happens if $X$ is a discrete set whose cardinality is a measurable cardinal? (See Gillman & Jerison, *Rings of Continuous Functions* for the general background on realcompact spaces.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen If $X$ is a discrete space or more generally a disjoint union of compacta, $\mathbb{R}^X$ is indeed Pontryagin-reflexive, since (if you trust Wikipedia) Kaplan showed that arbitrary products of Pontryagin-reflexive groups are Pontryagin-reflexive. Although there's the caveat that he probably didn't use the product in $k$-spaces, but it probably works anyways, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tangential to your query but I hope that it might be useful.  The duality for Banach spaces that you mention is, in my opinion, best expressed in terms of the symmetric one between between Banach spaces and Waelbroeck spaces.  The latter concept is due to Waelbroeck and Buchwalter and is perhaps easiest accessible in the classic text by Cigler, Losert and Michor  ("Functors on Categories of Banach Spaces").  A convenient way to look at it is in the context of the pro and ind categories (Grothendick et al.).  The category of Banach spaces (with linear contractions as morphisms) is the ind completion of the finite dimensional ones, that of Waelbrock spaces the pro-completion so the duality follows by abstract nonsense from the finite dimensional case.

With regard to the spaces of continuous functions, firstly I am of the opinion that the natural framework is that of (functionally separated) compactological spaces (again due to Buchwaltere, based on work by Waelbroeck) and the so-called Saks spaces.  The latter are Banach spaces with a suitable auxiliary l.c. topology on the unit ball.  One then considers a duality between a compactological spaces and the bounded continuous functions thereon, regarded as a Saks space with the uniform norm and the topology of compact convergence.  The details are too  convoluted to expose here but can be found in the monograph "Saks spaces and Applications to Functional Analysis (first edition)".  Once again, this duality is natural when considered in the context of pro and ind categories (applied to the categories of compact resp. Banach spaces).

One can also presumable develop a suitable  duality in terms of (not necessarily) bounded continuous functions as in your query, it is just that nobody has, to my knowledge, actually sat down and done this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first paragraph does not seem to be about what I am asking, though, since I am considering Banach spaces as topological vector spaces here, and not with short linear maps. As for the second  paragraph, here is a list of things that I am not aiming for: Saks spaces; convergence spaces and c-reflexivity (Butzmann et al.); stereotype spaces (Akbarov). The all have nice duality theories for spaces of continuous functions, but they don't come from natural mapping space topologies, as described in the question.

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph, if you're sure I can't just read it up somewhere, I would probably bother to "sit down and do this". ;) (One last note: I'm explicitly not considering just bounded functions, but the exponential $\mathbb{R}^X$.) And thanks again for taking your time to answer.

Comment: I would disagree with the comment that the Saks space structure doesn´t come from a natural mapping space topology (but that´s  just business, not personal).  If you want to work with compact convergence, the way to go would be to extend the symmetric duality between Banach spaces and Waelbroeck spaces to the corresponding pro and ind completions.  The former is the category of (complete) locally convex spaces, the latter a special class of convex bornological spaces, where the balls are provided with a suitable compact topology.  The latter has never been studied, to my knowledge.

Comment: By the way, I think that your objection to the use of contractions is a bit of a red herring.  They were only used as a a framework to place the extensions of duality from the special cases (finite dimensional, compact, etc.) in a unified setting.  This is an a posteriori approach--all of these extensions were made previously  without category theory and there is nary a word of contractions in the final version.

Comment: I didn't object to the use of contractions--why would I? I just had the impression that the duality you describe is different from the one mentioned in the question, but as you didn't go into detail, I can't really tell.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that this is not well-known:

> It is well-known that a Banach space $V$ is always *Pontryagin-reflexive*, i.e. the natural map $V\to \text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(\text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(V, \mathbb{R}), \mathbb{R})$, where $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(-, \mathbb{R})$ is endowed with the compact-open topology, is an isomorphism (of topological vector spaces).

Usually, when I say this, people are surprised, ask again, and don't really trust.

In my opinion, the nearest area to this is the theory of [stereotype spaces](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Stereotype_space) (in nLab it is mentioned [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stereotype+space)). Your type of reflexivity is called *reflectivity* and is studied in the works related to this theory, for example, [here](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1076.22001).

It is known that all Fréchet spaces are stereotype and, as a corollary, for $\sigma$-compact topological spaces $M$ the spaces ${\mathcal C}(M)$ of continuous functions (with the compact-open topology) are stereotype and satisfy your reflexivity condition (i.e. *reflectivity*). Moreover, as it was explained [here](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1042.46002), this is true for all paracompact locally compact spaces $M$.

Apart from the spaces ${\mathcal C}(M)$, there are many other functional spaces that are stereotype, in fact all the functional spaces in geometry:

- ${\mathcal E}(M)$ (the space of smooth functions on a smooth manifold $M$),
- ${\mathcal O}(M)$ (the space of holomorphic functions on a Stein manifold $M$),
- ${\mathcal P}(M)$ (the space of polynomials on an affine algebraic manifold $M$).

This is proved [here](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1042.46002). Also soon there must be published a book in De Gruyter titled "Stereotype spaces and algebras", where these questions are discussed in detail.

For arbitrary $k$-spaces $M$, as far as I remember, the spaces ${\mathcal C}(M)$ are not necessarily reflective (and not necessarily stereotype), but I can't recall a reference now. I remember that Salvador Hernandez and Vladimir Uspenskij studied close questions [here](https://in.art1lib.com/book/1934327/045ba5).

Comment: Thanks for answering! Regarding the last paragraph, do you remember a counterexample to the reflectivity (i.e. Pontryagin-reflexivity in the terminology of the original question) of $C(M)$ ($M$ arbitrary $k$-space)? I like your stereotype spaces; nevertheless, I think the precise question I posed is also intrinsically interesting, since it works completely in $\mathcal{Vect}_{\mathbb{R}}(k-\mathcal{Top})$, the category vector spaces internal to the category of $k$-spaces. So in a way, it's almost a naive question--which would make it interesting if the answer was positive.

Comment: By the way, I wrote that the result about Banach spaces is well known because it's both on the Wikipedia page for Pontryagin duality, and it appears in Peter Scholzes notes on Dustin Clausen's and his "Analytic Geometry" (/ "Condensed Mathematics").

Comment: @B.P. you know, I can't restore the details... Why it seems to me that this question has negative answer, I don't understand. I'll let you know if I recall this.